# Win32 ASM program prints nothing to command line

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, command-line, x86

I was trying writing a simple command line program in assembly using the Win32 API. I wrote the following, got it to compile and link with zero errors or warnings, and started it from a command line, but nothing appeared at the command prompt. Can anyone see what's wrong or what would make it say "Hello World!" at the command line? The program:

```
; Block 1
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

; Block 2
include windows.inc
include user32.inc
includelib user32.lib
include kernel32.inc
includelib kernel32.lib

; Block 3
.data
szMsg db "Hello World!",0
nNumToWrite dd 12

; Block 4
.data?
numwritten dd ?
CommandLine LPSTR ?

; Block 5
.code
start:
invoke GetCommandLine
mov CommandLine,eax
invoke WriteConsole,CommandLine,addr szMsg,nNumToWrite,numwritten,NULL
xor eax,eax
invoke ExitProcess,eax
end start
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? What did you find?

Comment: The parameters you're passing to `WriteConsole` are wrong. The first parameters should be a handle to the console output buffer and the fourth should be a pointer to the number of chars written (you're passing the value).

Comment: I change that line to `invoke WriteConsole,STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE,addr szMsg,nNumToWrite,addr numwritten,NULL` but still no joy.

Comment: @tenfour I can step through, but since I don't know at a low level how a Windows console program correctly puts characters on the terminal screen, I don't know if what I'm seeing is as it should be or not, especially while wading through the internals of the Win32 API functions.

Comment: I believe you need to get a handle to stdout, it won't just work by default. Try:   hConsole = CreateFile("CON:", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

Comment: `invoke  GetStdHandle,STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` / `mov hOut,eax` / `invoke WriteConsole,hOut,addr saMsg,nNumToWrite,addr numwritten,NULL` works for me. If your app is a GUI app (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) you'll probably have to call `AllocConsole` first.

Comment: @Michael Thanks! Now it works. I put your changes in my console project.

Answer (score 1):

Are you linking it as a console program or as a GUI program? That's a property of an executable in Win32.

Comment: I am using WinAsm. I did have the project as a Standard EXE when creating the project. I tried creating a new project in WinAsm and selecting Console Application as the project type and building with the same code, to the same result.